# Problem with React making Get request to Node(express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

As the title says, i have  a part of my react app that tries to get some data from my database, making a select based on the value I passed to it. So im gonna go ahead and first show the code where i think the problem lies:

So first, this is the function from one of my forms that sends the request to the server, i know code is probably ugly, but i can tell from the console.logs that the parameters im sending are what i intend to send(a string called "licenciaInput"

```
async handleClickLicencia (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log("licenciaInput: "+this.state.licenciaInput);
        const datoBuscar = this.state.licenciaInput;

        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/atletas/:licencia',this.state)
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)

            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log(error)
            })
```

And then, i have this function which is called in that localhost route which attempts to get "licencia", and launch a select in my postgresql db where licencia="whatever", you can see the sentence in the code:

```
const getAtletasByLicencia = (request, response) => {
   const licencia = request.body.licenciaInput;
   console.log("Request: "+request);
   console.log("what the server gets: "+licencia);
   // const licencia = request.licenciaInput;
   const sentencia ="SELECT * FROM atleta WHERE licencia ='"+licencia+"'";
   pool.query(sentencia, (error, results) =>{
        if(error){
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}
```

As you can see, i have console.logs everywhere, and i still cannot access whatever element i send, because i always get on the server console "undefined" value.

TLDR:How can i access the "licenciaInput" i passed from my client form to my server, i have tried request.body.licenciaInput, request.params.licenciaInput, and request.licenciaInput, but none of those seem to work

I also know i have to treat after that the data i receive from the server, but i need to solve this before looking two steps ahead. Im also really new to React and node/express, so feel free to burn me with good practices im not meeting.Thanks in advance

EDIT: Im also adding this code that i have which shows the route for my method in the server:

`app.get('/atletas/:licencia', db.getAtletasByLicencia)`

As @Gillespie59 suggested that i should send a POST request, but i dont think i should if im both trying to send a parameter to the server to make a select, and then send the results back to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request to:

```js
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/atletas/${this.state.licenciaInput}`)
  ...
```

and your route (if you are using express) should look like this:

```js
app.get('/atletas/:licencia', function (req, res) {
  var licencia = req.params.licencia
  ...
})
```

Comment: You are right, here is what i did wrong for anybody else that might find this question useful:
1: I didnt use the ${this.state.licenciaInput} in the get request, as i had :id because im new to this. 2: the name of the params i was requesting in my route was wrong, as it didnt match the one i had defined.Now i understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `request.body` you should send a POST request with axios and add a body.

Comment: I dont believe the problem lies here because im trying to retrieve data from the server, so im pretty sure i should use GET request

Comment: You use    const licencia = request.body.licenciaInput;

Comment: And as user Zirmax noted, thats where the mistake was, i should have written params instead of body, not change the request type because then i wouldnt be able to receive the data retrieved by the server from my get request with params.

Comment: You can use POST with body or GET with params.